# Get all the contents of a cell as text

Tags: google-sheets

I have two google spreadsheets. One of the sheets does all the math/formula while the second sheet pulls that data using the =IMPORTRANGE function. The data pulled is an URL. What I need is to extract just the contents of the cell.

[image]

I would like the contents of 'H1' to automatically paste to cell 'J1' in text format. I searched the web but every solution just talks about using "Ctrl + Shift + V" to copy and paste the 'values only'. Is there any way to automate this process and write a formula in cell 'I1' to extract the text from the formula cell which is 'H2' and paste it as text in cell 'J1'?

Comment: Sometimes I use this workaround, `=""&H1` would concatenate the string and the hyperlink would go off.

Comment: what's your ultimate goal? Why can't you just keep it as an URL?

Comment: my ultimate goal is to be able to copy the data I get and paste it anywhere else ( on other spreadsheets) and not copy the formula, currently, the issue is once I copy-paste it, unless I use the feature of 'ctrl + shift + V' i don't get the actual content of the cell. I end up with a formula which computes again and does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

use in J1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(H1:H&"")
```

Comment: is there a way to get just the data? if I copy-paste the new data after using the array formula on another sheet, I end up using the array formula again which checks the H1 cell again of the new sheet. I just want the copy-paste the data of the cell without taking in the formula again & avoiding to use 'ctrl+shift+v'

Comment: @FindTheWay possible but only with a script